# ListView and RecyclerView header item

Tags: android, listview, header, android-recyclerview

I would like some information (a library or specific name) to try to do that.
I want a listview or recyclerview with an item or header that dont scroll and when another specific item is on top of the screen stay that new item. 
Here an example in youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuHQSWQHxwk
Once I found a library to do that but I cant find it anymore.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library [StickyListHeader](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders). You can create view just like shown in the video you mentioned.